# listbox selected items into textbox not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

my vb.net will not use listbox1.selecteditems it always comes up with a blue line underneath even though when i search online everyone is using this.

my goal is to get the selected items and list them in a textbox

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim li As ListItem
        For Each li In ListBox1.Items
            If li.Selected Then
                TextBox1.Text &= li.Text & vbCrLf
            End If
            UpdatePanel2.Update()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the selection in a multi-selection list control

Loop through the control's Items collection and test the Selected property of every individual item.

```
For Each li In ListBox1.Items
   If li.Selected Then
      TextBox1.Text &= li.Text & vbCrLf
   End If
Next
```

[MSDN: To determine the selection in a multi-selection list control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5kfekd2%28VS.80%29.aspx)

SelectedItems is not available in ASP.Net, this property [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) only for Winforms-Listbox Controls.

Comment: Error 29 Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: You have to specify the DisplayMember(the text to display) and the ValueMember(the identifier) properties before Databinding.

Comment: You can't cast it to a Datarowview, it is a ListItem. A Listitem has a property Text and a property Value.

Comment: now theres no errors, but my textbox text doesnt change. It could be my update panels. but i dont think so i am going to try to do this in a blank project

Comment: Show us the markup of the UpdatePanel, is the Button inside of it? Otherwise call the update-method of this UpdatePanel after you have changed the Textbox.Text from the Codebehind.

Comment: i tryed ill update the code, this should be simple but its giving me the hardest time

Comment: You can also use the Listbox' SelectedIndexChanged Event as AsyncPostbackTrigger and handle that event instead of use the Button.
According to your last comment: what have you tried and what problems do you have? You can force the Update of the content of an UpdatePanel by calling its Update method. If the button would be inside of the Updatepanel and the Textbox is inside it too and the UpdatePanel has ChilderenAstriggers=true, you wouldn't need to do it manually.

Comment: You only need to update the UpdatePanel once instead of on every selected ListItem (not in the loop).

Comment: sorry, i had to leave my computer, i am going to try to use the selected index changed event, however, i am not updating the panel each time it loops.  and i am going to try and just put everything in the panel

Comment: I got it to work it was the updatepanels mainly because i have two on my page i guess both are updateing even though only one is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're binding to the control immediately prior to trying to retrieve a selected value from it.  When the control is initially bound to the datasource it won't have any selected items.

You need to split it out so that you bind the listbox when the page is loaded, then the user selects some things in that box, clicks your Button2, and the value of the textbox is updated on postback.

First, on page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs, e)
        listcmd.Connection = conn1
        conn1.Open()


        listcmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER"

        listda.Fill(saolist, "listboxtext")
        Dim dt As DataTable = saolist.Tables("listboxtext")

        ListBox1.DataSource = dt
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "SDESCR"
        ListBox1.DataMember = "SDESCR"
        ListBox1.DataBind()


        conn1.Close()
    End Sub
```

Then, this code is run when the user clicks Button2

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            TextBox1.Text &= DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItems(i), DataRowView)(1).ToString & vbCrLf
        Next

        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        TextBox1.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: the problem is i cant type listbox1.selecteditems (with an s at the end of items)

Comment: Error 29 'SelectedItems' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox'. C:\Documents and Settings\ChrisH\Desktop\AJAXEnabledWebSite4\Default.aspx.vb 301 33 C:\...\AJAXEnabledWebSite4\

Answer (score 0):

**To view (Text Item in textbox)**

textbox3.Text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);